# Debugging PHP code with Xdebug and PhpStorm

Tags: php, symfony, phpstorm, xdebug

I'm trying to enable Xdebug. I'm working on Ubuntu and I have trial PhpStorm version 2021.1.1.4.

My PHP version is 7.4:

```
PHP 7.4.21 (cli) (built: Jul  1 2021 16:09:41) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.4.0, Copyright (c) Zend Technologies
    with Zend OPcache v7.4.21, Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
    with Xdebug v3.0.4, Copyright (c) 2002-2021, by Derick Rethans
```

In file: /etc/php/7.4/cli/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini I have settings:

```
zend_extension=xdebug.so
xdebug.idekey=PHPSTORM
xdebug.default_enable=1
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

Symfony application is running on port 8000 and PhpStorm is listening debug like on the screen below:

[image]

I have also switched on the Xdebug Chrome extension:
[image]

What could be wrong? Why it doesn't stop on breakpoint?

EDIT:

Below I paste result of xdebug_info():

[image]

Comment: You have `with Xdebug v3.0.4` .. but using Xdebug v2 config. See https://xdebug.org/docs/upgrade_guide and upgrade to use new parameter names/values. That's the starting point for you right now.

Comment: So I need now only one line of settings: xdebug.mode=debug
Am I right?

Comment: *Might be enough.* I never do such limited config (always configure more than that) so cannot say for sure. Anyway, check https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/documentation/debugging/ and https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/debugging-with-phpstorm-ultimate-guide.html just in case.

Comment: With only this one line it still doesn't work.

Comment: Can you paste me your settings?

Comment: So show what you have: 1) show your current Xdebug live config (`xdebug_info()` output captured via browser) 2) enable Xdebug log, restart web server and try to debug. 3) You can place `xdebug_break();` in your PHP code and it should work as a programmatic breakpoint (in case if it does not see the Xdebug cookie or missing breakpoint).. And check the links on debugging (if you have not done PHP debugging with PhpStorm before)

Comment: Can you look on the bottom of my post? I've just pasted results of xdebug_info()

Comment: i think xdebug 3 runs on port 9003. did you tried changing in your php.ini?

Comment: 1) Do you have "phone handle" icon activated / green? It looks like PhpStorm does not listen on Xdebug port... 2) Just in case: show your Xdebug settings from PhpStorm (Settings | PHP | Debug). PhpStorm should listen on both old 9000 and new 9003 by default. You may try to change that to be 9003 only there.

Comment: Looking at your first screenshot again: 1) the "phone handle" icon is NOT green (the icon is on top right corner). When it's green then IDE listens to the incoming debug connections. 2) I do not see any Debug toolwindow .. which means that no Debug Configuration is currently running. Therefore it is absolutely expected to see that Xdebug fails to connect / no response ... since PhpStorm is not listening on Xdebug port at that moment

Comment: Now It works after creating file for logs.

Answer (score 0):

I was in the position as you, 3 months ago. Let me explain what i followed and got XDebug working. First of all download the latest version of Xdebug by copying and pasteing the output of your phpinfo() function https://xdebug.org/wizard

If you are on windows you need to place the .dll files of Xdebug in the php folder of your local server. Then open your php.ini and place the following lines at the bottom:

```
[xdebug]
zend_extension= <THE ABSOLUTE PATH TO THE XDEBUG FILE>
xdebug.mode=debug
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.client_host=127.0.0.1
xdebug.client_port=9003
xdebug.start_with_request = yes
xdebug.discover_client_host = 1
```

After you do that, open phpstorm on the settings/preferences tab go to the PHP Tab, go to the Xdebug section and enter Debug port 9000,9003, make sure can acept external connections is checked allong with the 3 checkboxes below from the Bebug port textfield.

Final step,close the settings window and at the top right  corner of phpstorm press the red telephone icon to start listening for incoming connections.

Refresh your browser and phpstorm should pop up a windows prompting you to accept the debug session.

I hope this helped you a lot.